# How do you determine what bash ls colours mean?

Tags: linux, shell, ls, ls-colors

When you perform `ls` in a bash shell, sometimes there are colours to indicate different resource types, and you can enable/control this with the `--color` argument.

But neither the man page nor Google is providing an answer to the question:

**What do these colours indicate by default, and how do I display what the current system uses?**

---

***UPDATE:***

Thanks everyone for answers so far, however to make it easier to pick a winner, can anyone go a step further and provide a method to output descriptions in the colours they apply to.

Hmmm... my example doesn't work when posted (only when previewed), so if you preview this code it'll show what I mean...

```
<ul style="list-style:none; background:black; margin:0;padding:0.5em; width:10em">
  <li style="color:blue">directory</li>
  <li style="color:aqua">symbolic link</li>
  <li style="color:#A00000;">*.tar files</li>
  <li style="color:white">...</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The colors are defined by the `$LS_COLORS` environment variable. Depending on your distro, it is generated automatically when the shell starts, using `~/.dircolors` or `/etc/DIR_COLORS`.

**Edit:**

To list color meanings, use this script:

```
eval $(echo "no:global default;fi:normal file;di:directory;ln:symbolic link;pi:named pipe;so:socket;do:door;bd:block device;cd:character device;or:orphan symlink;mi:missing file;su:set uid;sg:set gid;tw:sticky other writable;ow:other writable;st:sticky;ex:executable;"|sed -e 's/:/="/g; s/\;/"\n/g')
{
  IFS=:
  for i in $LS_COLORS
  do
    echo -e "\e[${i#*=}m$( x=${i%=*}; [ "${!x}" ] && echo "${!x}" || echo "$x" )\e[m"
  done
}
```

Comment: I believe that it uses BOTH - defaults are set in DIR_COLORS, and anything in ~/.dir_colors takes precedence.

Comment: Maybe... I don't know other distros, in Fedora, it is set in /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh, and it reads only one of them.

Comment: Thats a nice script, but I'd also like to be able to see the colors for extensions you don't have listed.

Comment: @Ian: All extensions? This set is virtually infinite, it makes no sense. Files that don't have a specific color uses the "normal file" color, that is listed by the script.

Comment: /etc/DIR_COLORS.xterm on redhat derivatives on remote access. otherwise you'll beat yourself silly trying to figure out why DIR_COLORS is already set to 1;34 and the environment still reports 0;34

Comment: Missing 'mh' in your translation table.

Answer (score 18):

Running the command `dircolors -p` will print all default colour settings.
See http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_dircolors.htm.

Comment: "dircolors -p" prints defaults, not the current settings

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to see the list of mappings in /etc/DIR_COLORS.  You can override that by creating .dir_colors in your home directory.

Answer (score 3):

Try "man 5 dir_colors" to see how it's set on your system.  Mine doesn't have /etc/DIR_COLORS so it must be set somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Google for **LS_COLORS** for some useful links.

**Edit:** To list the colors, this simple bash script may give an idea:

```
IFS=:
set $LS_COLORS
for C in $*
do
    IFS='='
    set $C
    echo -e "\033[$2m$1\033[00m"
done
```

Comment: Thanks Neil... unfortunately there isn't a way to accept a secondary/partial answer, and Juliano's one is slightly more complete.